# Where is the web icon in the app list for?

Tags: apps

In the app list, you can press a letter to go to the right section.
However, there is also an web icon at the end (right bottom).

[image]

What does it do? There is never an app under this section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's reserved for apps with characters not in the phone's native language, as described [here](http://www.windowscentral.com/what-does-globe-icon-mean-my-windows-phone).